# Javascript: Retrieve gmail contact return 401 using oauth2

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail

I have a HTML code for retrieving gmail contact

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full&state=contact&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&response_type=token&client_id=GMAIL_CLIENT_ID

All is working fine with redirect to gmail and then redirect to my callback URI and then showing all contact list,
And then since one month ago i can't use the same method.
I've tried using curl and it return error 401 without spesific error message.
Here is my javascript (jQuery) code using access token received from google

```
    $.fn.getGmailContact = function(){
        console.log(gmailAccessToken);
        if(!empty(gmailAccessToken)){
            console.log('test');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token='+ gmailAccessToken
            }).done(function(result){
                console.log(result);
                var $inviteCount = $('.invite-count');
                var $inviteList = $('.invite-list');

                // Clear html
                $inviteCount.html('');
                $inviteList.html('');

                // Parse xml to json
                result = xml2json(parseXml(result), "");
                result = JSON.parse(result);
                totalContact = result.feed.entry.length;

                $inviteCount.html('('+ result.feed.entry.length +')');

                if(result.feed.entry.length > 0){
                    var i = 1;
                    $.each(result.feed.entry, function(){
                        var li = '<li data-email="'+ this['gd:email']['@address'] +'">'+ 
                            this['gd:email']['@address'] +
                            '<input id="invite-'+ i +'" type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" style="display:none" value="" />'+
                            '<label class="invite-label" for="invite-'+ i +'" style="float:right;margin-top:6px;" onclick="jQuery().inviteSwitchCheck(this)" data-email="'+ this['gd:email']['@address'] +'"></label>'+
                        '</li>';
                        $inviteList.append(li);
                        i++;
                    });
                    $.facebox.loading();
                    $.facebox({div:'#invite-popup-container'}, 'facebox-popup-login');
                    $('#facebox .custom-facebox-title').html('INVITE CONTACTS FROM GMAIL');
                    $('#facebox #select-all-label').trigger('click');

                    if(i > 6){
                        $('#facebox #select-all-label').css({
                            marginRight: 18
                        });
                    }
                }
                // Destroy cookie
                $.cookie('gmail_access_token', null);
            }).always(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            });
        }
    }
```

Is there something wrong with my way of fetching data or is there is any changes on gmail without noticing developer?
My console only echo my access token and test string but there is no result var printed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know where those functions come from but it seems a little weird to me calling parseXml, then xml2json, and finally JSON.parse, since you should do that in 1 shot: Xml-to-JSObject.

Comment: @donkeydown thanks for your suggestion, i'll optimize the code.  How about gmail code, the code above is assuming that gmailAccessToken is not empty and it is not empty... I've got no result, my console only hit test and there is no "result"